# Radio buttons are being combined into one big group

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I’m using wxPython to build a “preferences” window that will contain many sets of radio buttons. According to [the wxWidgets documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxradiobutton.html)—(the wxPython docs omit the relevant information)—I should be able to specify `style=wx.RB_GROUP` for the first radio button in each group. Instead, though, all of the radio buttons are grouped together, so that clicking on one will deselect *all* of the others, whereas it should only deselect the other radio buttons in that group.

This behavior is demonstrated with this simple example:

```
import wx

class RadioTest(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        self.button_a_1 = wx.RadioButton(self, label='Group A, button 1',
                style=wx.RB_GROUP)
        self.button_a_2 = wx.RadioButton(self, label='Group A, button 2')
        self.button_a_3 = wx.RadioButton(self, label='Group A, button 3')

        sizer.Add(self.button_a_1)
        sizer.Add(self.button_a_2)
        sizer.Add(self.button_a_3)

        self.button_b_1 = wx.RadioButton(self, label='Group B, button 1',
                style=wx.RB_GROUP)
        self.button_b_2 = wx.RadioButton(self, label='Group B, button 2')

        sizer.Add(self.button_b_1)
        sizer.Add(self.button_b_2)

        self.SetSizer(sizer)

app = wx.App(False)

radio_test = RadioTest(None)
radio_test.Show()

app.MainLoop()
```

There should be two independent groups of radio buttons but there ends up being only one. I am using wxPython 2.9.4.0 via Homebrew on OS X 10.8.5. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading WX from 2.9.4.0 to 2.9.5.0 fixed this. These version numbers come from Homebrew and embarassingly, I’m not sure whether they refer to wxPython or to wxWidgets. Either way, there’s nothing in [the wxPython changelog](http://www.wxpython.org/recentchanges.php) or [the wxWidgets changelog](http://svn.wxwidgets.org/svn/wx/wxWidgets/trunk/docs/changes.txt) that seems relevant, so it’s a mystery to me why upgrading fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2):

The code you posted worked for me.  I'm putting this as an answer mostly so I can post a picture... as you can see, I can select two radio buttons, any of the top three, and any of the bottom two.

[image]

Are you sure the code you posted is what you ran?  I'm using '2.8.12.1' on OSX 10.6.8 (but I doubt that makes a difference on something so basic).

Comment: Upgrading to 2.9.5.0 fixed the problem for me (see my answer), so I guess there was some short-lived bug that was introduced after 2.8.12.1 and fixed in 2.9.5.0. \*shrug\* Thanks for your input!